# Why isn't my Unix time parsing consistently?

Tags: time, momentjs, unix-timestamp

My client generates a timestamp using Date.now(), generating a unix time in milliseconds.  But when I parse it later on the server, I get a very different date.  I can reproduce this discrepancy with [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpywh97x/2/).  My code is:

```
const parseMoment = moment('1603551654605', 'x').format();
const parseDate = new Date(1603551654605).toDateString();

alert(`moment: ${parseMoment}, date: ${parseDate}`);
```

The output I get is: `moment: 2020-11-16T00:00:00+01:00, date: Sat Oct 24 2020`

The correct output is what moment gives me here, 11/16. But moment on my server actually gives me the incorrect October date.  I need to reliably parse my unix timestamp back to the correct (later) date.

Comment: You are getting a wrong result in the jsfiddle, because you are using a very old moment version (2.2.1), you will not have this behaviour with more recent version (lastest 2.29.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix timestamp converts to **Saturday, 24 October 2020 15:00:54.605** (GMT)

---

`momentJS` does't require any second parameters while creating a date from **milliseconds** ([DOCS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)).

Using the correct conversion, both `moment()` and `new Date()` show the same result:

```js
const parseMoment = moment(1603551654605).format();
const parseDate = new Date(1603551654605).toDateString()

console.log(`moment\t: ${parseMoment}`);
console.log(`date\t: ${parseDate}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
moment : 2020-10-24T17:00:54+02:00
date   : Sat Oct 24 2020
```

Comment: What do you think the other date comes from then? This is the user’s last login time and I can tell from other evidence that this particular user logged in yesterday/today, not last month. It could be mere coincidence that the ‘x’ parse gives me what seems like the correct date, but could there be some difference in the way the ‘x’ calculation works that more faithfully reconstructs the original date?

Comment: I've used [epochconverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert the timestamp. So I'm quite sure the correct date is 24-oct. It hard to say where the other time is coming from since we have no idea how it's saved.

Comment: I think there was something wrong with the code capturing the lastLogin date in the first place, and I got fooled by the coincidence with the 'x' parser.  Considering deleting this question.